# Hide colored border with subview

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I have `uiview` with colored border. I want to add a subview above, so it "hide" parent view border. Currently when i try to add a view (subclass of UILabel) above it's not overlap anything as i want. What i want is remove white line when it interact with label frame.

[image]

My class is:

```
class LabeledContainerView: UIView {

  var text: String!
  var height: CGFloat!
  var offset: CGFloat!

  var label: UILabel = {
    let lbl = LabelSL.create(textColor: Theme.Color.white,
                               font: Theme.Font.regular())
    lbl.text = Strings.login.value
    lbl.backgroundColor = Theme.Color.clear.value
    return lbl
  }()

  init(text: String,
       height: Double,
       offset: Double) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    self.text = text
    self.height = CGFloat(height)
    self.offset = CGFloat(offset)
    createUI()
    setConstraints()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  func highlight(){

  }

  func turnOffHighlight(){

  }

  private func createUI(){
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    clipsToBounds = false
    layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    addSubview(label)
  }

  private func setConstraints(){
    let tinyOffset: CGFloat = 2

    label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: offset + tinyOffset).isActive = true
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without adding another view above it.
By set your textfield delegate to self then

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField.text?.isEmpty ?? false{
        //yourView.hideBorders
    }
}
```

If i didn't got your point please clarify

Answer (score 1):

You have set lbl.backgroundColor = Theme.Color.clear.value.
Thats why you can see the border. Set background color of label same as your view background color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure two things are happening:

- The UILabel is in front of the UITextField in the view hierarchy

This can be set either in the XIB file (storyboard) or programatically:

[image]

In the XIB depending on the where the view is in the list determines its priority. The higher it is in the list the further back it is. Therefore you want to move your label to be below your UITextField. You can drag and drop it in the left hand list.

You can also set this programatically by pushing your textField to the back of the hierarchy:

```
sendSubviewToBack(UITextField)
```

- The UILabel has a background colour

This can also be set programatically or in the XIB:

Programatically:

```
label.backgroundColor = .red
```

XIB:

[image]

Checking these two things will ensure that the UILabel is in front of the UITextField and covers the border when it has text.